# Inverse of a number in Zx

Tags: java

Sorry, I can't translate what inverse is exactly.

I'm looking for a Java library(if any) or algorithm that calculates something like inverse of `5` in `Z9`. That is like `5^-1=2`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To compute the inverse of `x` mod `m`, use

```
BigInteger.valueOf(x).modInverse(BigInteger.valueOf(m)).intValue();
```

Comment: Yup, that worked. Thanks. I can't translate this in english, though. How do you call Zx? Or all the mathemathical theory behind this.

Comment: We use the same notation in English.

Comment: @GeorgeIrimiciuc Integers modulo x, but the notation is the same. The arithmetic used is called [modular arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic).

Comment: I know, but I'm looking for what it's called, for theory.

Comment: @NiklasB. Thanks, found out "primitive residue classes modulo n"

Comment: Wolfram calls this the [modular inverse](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModularInverse.html). Either I was unfamiliar with the concept, or I was taught it so long ago and used it so little that I had completely forgotten about it.